# An app that can give me the amount of time using an app?

Tags: macos, mac, applications, time-tracking

I need an app that tracks automatically every time I use Final Cut X or another app and gives me the total usage time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use **RescueTime**. It's quite cool + for free you get a lot of features

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

### Option A

Option A is to create an alias:

```
alias timeon='ps -ax -o etime,command -c | grep'
```

then you can run:

```
timeon Safari
```

### Option B

If you're comfortable with the shell you can use:

```
ps -ax -o etime,command -c
```

and attempt to locate the app. For me, `Safari` looks like:

```
   01:57:18 Safari
```

You an also pipe it through `grep`:

```
ps -ax -o etime,command -c | grep "Safari$"
```